# Is this the right way to use BouncyCastle.net to get an AES derived key from ECDH?

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle

```
X9ECParameters curve = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-521");
ECDomainParameters ecparam = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N,      curve.H, curve.GetSeed());
ECKeyPairGenerator generator = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
generator.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecparam, new SecureRandom()));

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ackp1 = generator.GenerateKeyPair();
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ackp2 = generator.GenerateKeyPair();
```

then,

```
ECDHWithKdfBasicAgreement agreement = new ECDHWithKdfBasicAgreement("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.42", new ECDHKekGenerator(DigestUtilities.GetDigest("SHA256")));
    agreement.Init(ackp1.PrivateKey);
    BigInteger agInt = agreement.CalculateAgreement(ackp2.PublicKey);
    byte[] aeskey = agInt.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
```

This goes through without generating any errors and I verified that the "aeskey" is the same when I swap in the other pair of public/private keys.

I found zero examples of this kind of usage with google.
The code seems correct to me, bu having to provide the Der OID for AES256 (instead of the string "AES256", which bombs in CalculateAgreement) makes me suspicious that I am doing something wrong.

this was reposted from [This question on crypto.stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14353/is-this-the-right-way-to-use-bouncycastle-net-to-get-an-aes-derived-key-from-ecd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be heading in the right direction though I'm not sure your OID is correct. It looks very suspicious to me, a quick internet search did not show up any expected results.

According to RFC 2631:

> algorithm is the ASN.1 algorithm OID of the CEK wrapping algorithm
>        with which this KEK will be used. Note that this is NOT an
>        AlgorithmIdentifier, but simply the OBJECT IDENTIFIER. No
>        parameters are used.

So the use of an OID is correct, but the OID itself may not be. I would expect an OID that indicates e.g. AES in CBC or GCM mode. This won't show up if you use an invalid OID on both sides of course, it is only used to generate your key, not when you actually use it.

Note that the code of Bouncy Castle seems to be vulnerable to a bug that was also in the Java DH code: a `BigInteger` is always encoded in the minimal number of bytes. However, the key generated by any normal key agreement is a specific number of bytes, including initial `00` valued bytes. This means that just calling `BigInteger.ToByteArray` will generate the wrong number of bytes (or an illegal value) once in about 256 bytes as leading zero's will be lost during the conversion. Again, this won't make any differences in operation during testing against identical code on the same system. But the DH used against other systems will fail now and then (I've reported this to Bouncy for Java and it has been confirmed and then fixed in Bouncy 1.50)...

Comment: NOte that I'm also not 100% sure that the C# code in Bouncy to calculate the key size (using G.X) is correct, normally the order parameter is used instead. It will work on most curves I suspect, but it may not work on *all*.

Comment: Thanks for the info ! I will check my OID once more. Could you also point me to the Java source for the bugs you mention ? I can try to hunt down the matching C# source and fix it. The C# version is about 2 years old, so I bet it does not have these fixes

Comment: you were right, the OID was wrong. I used NistObjectIdentifiers.IdAes256Cbc.ToString() instead.

Comment: @owlstead Could you clarify your comment about normally using the order parameter? Latest code uses the curve field size which is the usual size in e.g. point encodings; is that what you meant here?

Comment: @PeterDettman I'll give this a bit of additional research. I read somewhere that the order *should* be normally used to determine the size, but now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

ECDHWithKdfBasicAgreement is a little awkward since it's a port of something that only exists in the JCE parts of the Java build. As @owlstead points out you need to deal with the BigInteger/byte[] conversion. In this case, with latest code, you can use:

```
int keyLen = GeneratorUtilities.GetDefaultKeySize(algorithm) / 8;
byte[] key = BigIntegers.AsUnsignedByteArray(keyLen, agInt);
```

or of course, just pad it out to the size you known you need. I think the AES256 thing is fixed in latest code too. Code is now on github (https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp), but a new beta build of C# is (finally) a mere day or two away also.